# Get via XPATH to value of the tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a doubt about XSLT. I'm trying get via XPATH to value of the tag  but I don't know how can I do it.

I'm tryng acces with this XPTAH:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role=&apos;C&apos; and ./@id=&apos;atom1&apos;]/*/Table1/Nombre">
```

but it's impossible.

I also tried with code:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role=&apos;C&apos; and ./@id=&apos;atom1&apos;]/DescargarFicheroPendienteResponse/DescargarFicheroPendienteResult/Table1/Nombre">
```

I think th problem is the tag:

This is the example XML:

```
<Payload Role="C" id="atom1" statusNo="0" statusMsg="success" reference="atom2" payload="atom2" calltype="solicit response (call/reply)" adapter="WSAS">  
    <http.header>  
        <http.header.info id="X-AspNet-Version" value="2.0.50727"/>  
        <http.header.info id="Date" value="Wed, 24 Jul 2013 10:23:53 GMT"/>  
        <http.header.info id="Content-Length" value="494"/>  
        <http.header.info id="MicrosoftOfficeWebServer" value="5.0_Pub"/>  
        <http.header.info id="Content-Type" value="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/>  
        <http.header.info id="Server" value="Microsoft-IIS/6.0"/>  
        <http.header.info id="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET"/>  
        <http.header.info id="Cache-Control" value="private, max-age=0"/>  
    </http.header>  
    <DescargarFicheroPendienteResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
        <DescargarFicheroPendienteResult>  
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">  
                <Table1>  
                    <Nombre>0</Nombre>  
                    <Contenido/>  
                </Table1>  
            </NewDataSet>  
        </DescargarFicheroPendienteResult>  
    </DescargarFicheroPendienteResponse>  
</Payload>
```

anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: You should at first reconsider you question. Your example xml does not match your xpath at all. (xpath start with `MSg` but xml with `Payload`. You need also to show a small working version off your xslt. We can't see if you add the namespace accurately etc.. Why do you use `&apos;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this in the XML:

```
<DescargarFicheroPendienteResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" ....>  
    <DescargarFicheroPendienteResult>  
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table1>
```

an XPath expression

```
vpf:Payload[....]/DescargarFicheroPendienteResponse/
   DescargarFicheroPendienteResult/Table1/Nombre
```

will definitely not work - firstly, in the XML your `DescargarFicheroPendienteResponse` and `DescargarFicheroPendienteResult` elements are in the `http://tempuri.org/` namespace so you will need to map that to a prefix in the stylesheet (e.g. `xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/"`) and then use that prefix in the XPath, and secondly there's a `NewDataSet` element above the `Table1`.

```
vpf:Payload[....]/t:DescargarFicheroPendienteResponse/
    t:DescargarFicheroPendienteResult/NewDataSet/Table1/Nombre
```